# What's the best practice for handling the object ownership in RESTful API?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got some problem with the object ownership on my restful API,
It is written using .net core 2.0 and its authentication process follows the OIDC implicit flow using IdentityServer4, for authorization, I'm using my custom middleware which converts the role and permissions to the claims identity which is validated by some custom authorization policy provider.
I'm also using SQL Server as database which is accessed via entity framework core 2. I'm following the code first approach.

The problem is some resources had a owner id as foreign key, this means only their owner and users with admin role can perform CRUD on them. 
Now I must check this ownership in each action of these controllers, it makes my code duplicate and dirty to get the user id from token then use it as owner id for each action, also I have to create a flow for admins users who are not the real owners.

What's the best practice for this problem?